# Only roundup if ends with .4 or above

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone help me with a formula that roundups up a number only if it ends with .4 or more, otherwise it should stay as it is.

Eg. 
1.4 rounds to 2 ;
2.5 rounds to 3 ;
2.3 stays at 2.3

Perhaps i should also mention that the number that needs rounding may sometimes have more than 1 decimal place

Hopefully this is clear enough

Comment: Please next time add a language tag. I added the `Excel-formula` tag, if that's not what you want, change it to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`=FLOOR(num+0.6,1)` will do the trick.

Comment: This gives me too few arguments error as significance not specified.

Comment: Thanks - fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
=IF(ROUND(A1+0.1,0)>A1,ROUND(A1+0.1,0),A1)
```

Comment: V nice and simple!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after.

**Formula**

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>2,IF(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,1))>3,ROUNDUP(A1,0),A1),A1)
```

**Explanation**

- `LEN(A1)>2` Check if cell is 3 characters or more. Whole numbers are 1, so ignore them
- `MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,1)` - Find the character to the right of the decimal point. Returns text..
- `NUMBERVALUE(...)>3` - Convert that text, and check it is greater than 3.
- `ROUNDUP(A1,0)` - **Only if that is true**, round up the number. Otherwise return it as it is.

**Example**

[image: Rounded Data]

Comment: `FIND(".",A1)` - you'd better hope your users are all using period as decimal separator.

Comment: True enough. I assume this is for OP's own use; divider doesn't matter as long as it's consistent as `FIND(",",A1)` could be used. Changing locale settings on own machine or sending user with different locale will not work.